# XCopy is not working (File not found *.*)

Tags: cmd, windows-10, xcopy

I'm tyring to copy a folder from my Visual Studio 2015 Project's root directory into the output directory (as it breaks the application without it), so I decided to add xcopy to the post-build commands.

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Content\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Content\" /s /i /y
```

I'm getting the following when it runs, and right now I can't even test this application because of xcopy.

```
1>  File not found - *.*
1>  0 File(s) copied
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy "E:\Data\Projects\Vessel\Games\TheThing\Content\*.*" "E:\Data\Projects\Vessel\Games\TheThing\TheThing\bin\DesktopGL\AnyCPU\Debug\Content\" /s /i /y" exited with code 4.
```

Comment: I would double check that your `$(SolutionDir)Content` exsits. That error indicates that your source doesn't exist

Comment: Typing `net helpmsg 4` returns `The system cannot open the file.`. Close the file before copying.

Comment: @nick Yes it exists as I created it.

Comment: @CatCat its not open as its a directory

Comment: @Hyblocker but a file inside the directory could be open, which could prevent the copy

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting problems with Xcopy and postbuild events in visual studio from time to time. 
My fix is generally to create a batch script which contains the xcopy.

The batch script then is called by:

```
call "$(SolutionDir)scripts\copyfiles.bat"
```

as a post script event.

Comment: I ran the xcopy command (from the Visual Studio 2015 output) in cmd, and it still didn't work :(

Comment: So I realised that instead of all that work, I could go to the all of the file's properties and set their "Copy to output Directory" from "Do not copy" to "Copy always"